# Таблица Pandas в JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

Есть таблица пандас вида:

```
iterables = [["2020Q1", "2020Q2"], ["yugo_id_1", "yugo_id_2"]]
table_1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['result'], index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, 
                                             names = ["preiod", "yugo_id"]), data = [1,2,3,4])
table_1
```

```
                  result
preiod  yugo_id 
2020Q1  yugo_id_1   1
        yugo_id_2   2
2020Q2  yugo_id_1   3
        yugo_id_2   4
```

При конвертировании ее в формат JSON получаю следующий массив:

```
result = table_1.to_json(orient="index")
parsed = json.loads(result)
parsed
```

```
{"('2020Q1', 'yugo_id_1')": {'result': 1},
 "('2020Q1', 'yugo_id_2')": {'result': 2},
 "('2020Q2', 'yugo_id_1')": {'result': 3},
 "('2020Q2', 'yugo_id_2')": {'result': 4}}
```

При этом мне нужно, чтобы JSON имел следующую структуру:

```
{
"2020Q1": { "yugo_id_1": {'result': 1},
            "yugo_id_2": {'result': 2}
          },

"2020Q2": { "yugo_id_1": {'result': 3},
            "yugo_id_2": {'result': 4}
          }    
}
```

По идее, формат таблицы пандас может быть любым, главное, чтобы на выходе получился нужный JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
def df_to_dict(df):
    if df.ndim == 1:
        return df.to_dict()

    ret = {}
    for key in df.index.get_level_values(0):
        sub_df = df.xs(key)
        ret[key] = df_to_dict(sub_df)
    return ret
print(json.dumps(df_to_dict(table), indent=4))
```